# Request to reopen my question

Tags: support

[This](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/45477/22556) is the question I asked.

It has been closed as a duplicate. But the duplicate doesn't answers my question.

My question is about satvik rajasik tamasik **food** mentioned in gita.

And not about satvik rajasik tamasik it self.

Please reopen my question.

Comment: The question seems to be already reopened now

Comment: @Pandya it was closed now it is opened